# React - Axios/Fetch/Ajax request after new props passed to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have two components, App and Child. My goal is that App passes an id down to Child and when Child receives it as props, I want Child to perform an Axios/Fetch request and then update itself with the result data. I will accept any answer that provides me with an example App/Child source code that completes my example or gives my insight if this is actually possible what I'm trying to implement.

I am a new to React.

// App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Child from './Child.js';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    id: 0
  };

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      id: this.state.id + 1
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child id={this.state.id} />
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Pass new id down to Child component</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

// Child.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Child extends Component {
    state = {
        data: null,
        id: 0
    };

    loadData(q, cb) {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3000/foo?q='+this.state.id)
        .then(result => {            
            // ?
            // this.setState would retrigger update and create an infinite updating loop
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('error: ' + error);
        });
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, prevState) {
        console.log('shouldComponentUpdate: nextProps = ' + JSON.stringify(nextProps) + ', prevState = ' + JSON.stringify(prevState));        

        // ??
    }

    getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(nextProps, prevState) {
        console.log('getSnapshotBeforeUpdate: nextProps = ' + JSON.stringify(nextProps) + ', prevState = ' + JSON.stringify(prevState));

        // ?? 
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        console.log('getDerivedStateFromProps: nextProps = ' + JSON.stringify(nextProps) + ', prevState = ' + JSON.stringify(prevState));
        return {
            id: nextProps.id
        };

        // ?? 
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log('componentDidUpdate');
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <div>data = {this.state.data}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

Comment: In `componentDidUpdate()`, compare `prevProps.id` and `this.state.id`. If they are different, call `loadData()`. (I also don't see how your current could would create an infinite loop?)

Comment: because loadData triggers setState which will trigger componentDidUpdate eventually

Comment: But that's no loop yet. In order for it to be a loop, `componentDidUpdate()` would have to *always* call `loadData()`. That doesn't happen though, only when the `id` has changed. It's been like 7 weeks, are you still stuck on this and didn't even try my suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call check prev Id with current id to avoid recursive update. You just need to make sure you only derive state from props if your props have changed,

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.id !== prevState.id) {
    return {
        id: nextProps.id
    };
 }
 return null;

}
```

Let me know if your issue still persists

Comment: If props changed and state gets updated you’ll call loadData in componentDidUpdate

Comment: why there? it will call setState which will update componentDidUpdate again ( and again)

Comment: No you put a check in componentDidUpdate to avoid unnecessary setState calls

Answer (score -1):

## This could be one way to go about your problem,

### Firstly, you'll have to update all the state data inside your getDerivedStateFromProps

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.id !== prevState.id) {
    // Returning this object is equivalent to setting state using this.setState    
        return {
            id: nextProps.id
            data: loadData(nextProps.id) // Something like this
        };
    }
    return null; // Indicates no state change
}
```

### As for the api call inside `loadData` method you can make use of the aync / await to return the data from api call

```
async loadData(id) {
    try {
        // Make your api call here
        let response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/foo?q='+id);
        return await response.json();
    } catch(err) {
        // catches errors both in axios.get and response.json
        // Make sure to not update state in case of any error
        alert(err);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note:

> - This is not the complete solution as you might want to not update the state in the case where your api call in `loadData` catches any error.
> - Also, since you are using api calls, you might want to limit the times pass props to the child cause they all will trigger different api calls and you will run into unpredictable states. Try debouncing.